# AmCharts maps zoom bug on touchscreen devices

Tags: javascript, zooming, amcharts, touchscreen, ammap

I had a bug on amCharts maps (amMaps): on touchscreen devices if you zoom using fingers and they are not exactly touching the screen, the zoomed area jumps. I am using Worldlow map (https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/enabling-zooming-map-mouse-wheel)

How to replicate:

1. Go to this Amcharts Wordlow map using touchscreen device: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/enabling-zooming-map-mouse-wheel/
2. touch with both fingers on screen and zoom, keeping fingers on screen.
3. leave one finger, keeping the other, and touch other parts of the map. you will see the map jumping!

I asked to amCharts Customer Support a solution, but still no news. If you experienced the same bug and found a smart solution to have a working map on touchscreen devices I will appreciate!

Comment: None interested to fix this big bug on amCharts Map?